# Estou tentando fazer meu gráfico começar da posição 0 usando hist()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ipython-notebook

Utilizando o USAGE_PLOT ficou fácil de se fazer mas quero fazer e aprender a utilizar o hist. do mesmo jeito que está na imagem abaixo  em que foi utilizado
`usage_plot(trip_data, 'duration', ['duration < 60'], boundary = 0, bin_width = 5)`
[image: resultado]

Mas estou tentando várias coisas diferentes e não estou conseguindo chegar ao mesmo resultado:

```
plt.figure()

trip_data_ex = trip_data[trip_data['duration'] < 60]

data_plot_ex = trip_data
data_plot_ex['count'] = 1

data_plot_ex = trip_data_ex.groupby('duration', as_index=False).count()
x_data = trip_data_ex['duration'].unique()
min_value = data_plot_ex['duration'].min()
bins = [i*5 + min_value -1 for i in range(13)]

plt.hist(data_plot_ex['count'], bins, width=4.9)

plt.show()
```

[image: Mais próximo que cheguei.]

Alguma idéia de como conseguir chegar na primeira imagem ?
Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Os número são completamente diferentes (8000 vs 800) ==> imagens diferentes...

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137854/how-to-make-the-histograms-touch-in-pylab) que usa o `pylab.hist` como o parâmetro `histtype="stepfilled"` . 
Caso isto não funcione, você pode tentar usar [barras assimétricas](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html), aumentando o tamanho das barras problemáticas.

Se nenhuma destas coisas funcionarem, como você ter barras juntas e comecando do zero, você pode facilmente modificar a sua data e plotar uma [area](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html) ou [patch](https://glowingpython.blogspot.se/2015/04/stacked-area-plots-with-matplotlib.html). A data precisa de um pouco de atencão para fazer os pontos, pois algumas técnicas usam entradas levemente diferentes. Mas o tempo não deve ser muito diferente de fazer as barras assimétricas.